# How to animate something when WithAnimation cannot be used?

Tags: animation, swiftui, transition

I have a bunch of elements on a VStack which visibility depends on a bool. Like this

```
if numberOfArrayElementsWithValidNames() != 0 {
  Button1()
  Button2()
  Button3()
}
```

That array is manipulated by many forms, and the array may contain elements with valid or invalid names. This is why I cannot use `withAnimation` to animate this.

If the number of valid elements on that array is zero, I want the buttons to disappear; otherwise, if the count is not zero anymore, they should appear. But I want them to appear/disappear with fade in/fade out, not suddenly as they are doing now.

How do I do this?

Comment: Use `.animation(_, value: _)` on the `View` itself rather than `withAnimation`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already suggested in the comments and another answer, you can make the animation more specific by using an `.animation` modifier. However, if you use the array as the `value` for the modifier, you may still get some unwanted animation in other parts of the view, just as you had before.

I would suggest creating a computed property to evaluate the condition for showing the buttons. Then use this as the value for the `.animation` modifier.

Like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var names: [String] = []

    private var arrayHasElementsWithValidNames: Bool {
        return names.firstIndex(of: "Valid") != nil
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Color.yellow.frame(height: 20)
            demoControls
            if arrayHasElementsWithValidNames {
                Button("Button1") {}
                Button("Button2") {}
                Button("Button3") {}
            }
            Color.orange.frame(height: 20)
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: arrayHasElementsWithValidNames)
    }

    var demoControls: some View {
        VStack {
            Grid(horizontalSpacing: 30) {
                GridRow {
                    Text("Array size")
                    Text("Number of valid names")
                }
                GridRow {
                    Text("\(names.count)")
                    Text("\(names.filter { $0 == "Valid" }.count)")
                }
            }
            .drawingGroup()
            Button("Add valid name") { names.append("Valid") }
            Button("Add invalid name") { names.append("Invalid") }
            Button("Remove valid name") {
                if let index = names.firstIndex(of: "Valid") {
                    names.remove(at: index)
                }
            }
            Button("Remove all") { names.removeAll() }
        }
        .padding()
        .border(.blue)
        .buttonStyle(.bordered)
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. But you can also use withAnimations in the buttons. Actually I don't see why it can't be used in the first place, although admittedly it would be more code, so this solution is better.

Comment: isn't withAnimation just to be used when you change a property? Example: showButtons.toggle() ? In this case, it would be tied to a var that will check if the array has valid elements or not

Answer (score 1):

As @jnpdx said. In this circumstance, you can use `animation(_:value:)`. It's an explicit animation, it will trigger when the `value` changes. I'm assuming it's `elements`.

```swift
Button1()
    .opacity(numberOfArrayElementsWithValidNames == 0 ? 0 : 1)
    .animation(.easeInOut, value: elements)
```